# How do I change VS19 path to IIS Express?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-express

How do I change default path of Visual Studio 19 for IIS Express?

I'm getting error :

> "An error occurred launching IIS Express. Unable to launch configured Visual Studio Development Web Server. Unable to start program 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe'
>   The system cannot find the file specified.'

That is because it's not correct path. I need to change it to 'C:\Users\user\Documents\IISExpress' or
'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express' if I'm correct.

How do I change that path? Did someone experienced the same problem?

Comment: Visual Studio assumes IIS Express is always installed there. If you want to use another path, launch IIS Express from command line, and then attach VS to that process.

Comment: How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the installation directory is default which we cannot modify. It will automatically install at “C:\Program Files\IIS Express\” & “ C:\Program Files(x86)\IIS Express”. And “C:\Users\user\Documents\IISExpres” is use to save configure file and log file.

Did this error happen when you debugging web project? If so, hope these suggestions could help you troubleshoot it:

•   Download IIS [Express.msi](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48264), then run it to repair IIS express on your machine

•   Clear IIS Express folder in “C:\Users\user\Documents”, then restart visual studio

•   Run visual studio as administrator

•   Open C:\Users\user\Documents\IISExpres\config\applicationhost.config, then comment out “HttpLoggingModule” line

```
<add name="HttpLoggingModule" image="%IIS_BIN%\loghttp.dll" />
<add name="HttpLoggingModule" lockItem="true" />
```

In addition, you could try other solutions here: [Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171656/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server)